# macro to open and go to hidden sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry as I am very new to this and cobbling together what I can. The below allows me to go to an open sheet via entry in an input box but I need it to open a hidden sheet then go to it. Again, sorry for my poor wording but any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub SearchSheetName()
    Dim sName As String
    Dim sFound As Boolean

    sName = InputBox(prompt:="Enter BAC to find in workbook:", Title:="Sheet search")

    If sName = "" Then Exit Sub
    sFound = False

    On Error Resume Next
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sName).Select
        If Err = 0 Then sFound = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    If sFound = False Then
        MsgBox prompt:="The sheet '" & sName & "' No Data or Non Assigned Account!", Buttons:=vbExclamation, Title:="Search result"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub SearchSheetName()
    Dim sName As String, sht As Worksheet

    sName = InputBox(prompt:="Enter BAC to find in workbook:", Title:="Sheet search")

    If sName = "" Then Exit Sub

    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sName) '<< try setting a reference...
    On Error GoTo 0

    If sht Is Nothing Then
        'sheet not found...
        MsgBox prompt:="The sheet '" & sName & _
            "' No Data or Non Assigned Account!", _
            Buttons:=vbExclamation, Title:="Search result"
    Else
        If sht.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then sht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        sht.Select
    End If

End Sub
```